# Is there a difference in focus between "I'm working in my room" and "I'm in my room working" due to the word order?

Tags: difference, word-order

Do these mean the same thing or is there a different focus in each?

> I'm working in my room.
>
> I'm in my room working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in so many situations, it depends on context. Although *I’m working in my room* is the more natural of the two as a response to a question like ***What** are you doing?*, the prepositional phrase *in my room* feels a bit irrelevant to that question. And *I’m working in my room* is also the more natural of the two as a response to an essentially **where?** question like *Are you in the office today or on telework?*

It’s also important to bear in mind that listeners and readers tend to interpret utterances as having the novel information, the payload, at the end. Thus,

> I’m on task at home

reads as though it’s acknowledging the importance of working on the task, but highlighting that it’s at home that the working is happening, whereas

> I’m at home on task

has more the sense of, “Sure I’ve stayed home sick today, but that isn’t keeping me from working on the task.”

Answer (score 2):

They mean the same thing with a slightly different emphasis.

I am **working** in my room.
I am **in my room** working.

Answer (score 2):

"I'm working in my room" emphasizes the **activity** you're engaged in.

"I'm in my room working" emphasizes the **location** first.

Both sentences convey a similar idea with subtle differences.